# Tweepy returned User has not attribute follower_count

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm using a flask web app and I'm trying to return the tweepy results of the user screen name and follower count and post them to flask. I get a 500 error when visiting domain.com/tweet

```
@app.route("/tweet")
def tweet():
user = api.get_user('twitter')
return (user.screen_name, user.follower_count)
```

Is there a way to do this, I feel like i'm massively over simplifying everything, Do i need to log the tweets into a database first ?

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'follower_count'
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be **followers_count**. Check Twitter docs [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object).

Comment: Thanks that worked, silly mistake. However when I access the page it only gives returns the name of the user and not the screen name and follower account